# Java interfaces, generic and not knowing what I'm doing

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, interface, compiler-warnings

(Disclaimer: I'm an long time programmer, only I'm not that used at Java.)

Hi all.

I've just finished adding a new functionality to my Android app, everything work quite well, but I'm not sure what I've done :-D and Eclipse give me 3 warnings. And I hate having unresolved warnings :-)

The code, first:

```
public interface IClass<T> {
    public ArrayList<T> getSomething();
    [a few other public methods, not relying on T]
}

public class Class1 implements IClass<String>{
    public ArrayList<String> getSomething(){
        [code]
    }

    [the other public methods]
}

public class Class2 implements IClass<long>{
    public ArrayList<long> getSomething(){
        [code]
    }

    [the other public methods]
}
```

Then I've got a third class, call it **ConsumerClass**: declare a variable of type **IClass**, with an if on a specific condition instantiate it to **new Class1()** or **new Class2()**, in the rest of the code it works on it as a generic **IClass** where needed and, in the only one spot it calls **getSomething()**, does a cast.

As I said, everything work as expected. "Problem" is that Eclipse gives me 3 warning and, not really being so good at Java, I'd like to understand them and if what I did is correct, because after all I coded the thing...well, by instinct.

Warnings are:

1. IClass is a raw type. References to generic type IClass should be parameterized
2. Type safety: Unchecked cast from ArrayList to ArrayList
3. Type safety: Unchecked cast from ArrayList to ArrayList

First it's total darkness to me.
Last two I can understand, only I don't know how to check the result of a call without doing it. I mean:

```
ArrayList<String> res = (ArrayList<String>) IClass_Instance.getSomething();
```

How can I check the type of **IClass_Instance.getSomething()** without calling it?

Thx all :-)

Comment: What is `IClass_Instance`? The name suggests it's a variable (so what is its type?) but the name starts with a capital, which is reserved for types by the Java coding conventions.

Comment: I've tested what your code would be and got no compiler problem. Please provide the necessary code to replicate your problem, otherwise the question is off topic for the site.

Comment: `IClass<long>` is illegal - you can only use object types - try with `IClass<Long>`.

Comment: can you show the declaration of IClass_Instance ?

Comment: For declaration, as I said below is:
private IClass IClass_Istance;


@OldCurmudgeon: IClass<long> was just to reduce 6 files and a few thousands lines of code to something understandable, in the real code both the class implements the interface with T being two other custom classes from the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide your IClass type variable declaration, I will assume that you do it this way:

```
Iclass iClass_Instance = new Class1();
```

Even though you call `Class1()` constructor, your variable still has `IClass` type. So when you call your `getSomething()` method, the compiler doesn't know which type is `<T>` because you didn't specify it in your variable type declaration, hence the warning.

You should declare your variable like this:

```
IClass<String> iClass_Instance = new Class1();
```

This way the compiler knows that your IClass instance is in fact of type IClass, regardless of which constructor you call.

**EDIT:**

I don't know the domain, but you are probably taking a wrong design decision. This sounds like the typical situation where you need a **hierarchy of interfaces**. Something like:

```
public interface ParametrizedInterface<T> {
    public List<T> getParametrizedList();
}

public interface StringInterface extends ParametrizedInterface<String> {}

public interface IntegerInterface extends ParametrizedInterface<Integer> {}
```

And the **implementations**:

```
public class ParametrizedImplementation<T> implements ParametrizedInterface<T> {

    private List<T> elements;

    public ParametrizedImplementation() {
        elements = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> getParametrizedList() {
        return this.elements;
    }
}

public class RightStringImplementation implements StringInterface {

    List<String> elements;

    public RightStringImplementation() {
        elements = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getParametrizedList() {
        return this.elements;
    }
}

public class StringImplementation implements ParametrizedInterface<String> {

    private List<String> elements;

    public StringImplementation() {
        elements = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public List<String> getParametrizedList() {
        return this.elements;
    }
}

public class IntegerImplementation implements ParametrizedInterface<Integer> {

    private List<Integer> elements;

    public IntegerImplementation() {
        elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }

    public List<Integer> getParametrizedList() {
        return this.elements;
    }

}
```

With this you have real **type safety**:

```
public class HierarchyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // You could do things like this
        ParametrizedInterface testObj = new StringImplementation();

        // This compiles because you don't specify the type of the parameter
        // when you declare the variable.
        List<Integer> elements = testObj.getParametrizedList();
        // ...

        // You should do things like this
        // With the parametrized implementation
        ParametrizedInterface<String> strObj = new ParametrizedImplementation<String>();

        List<String> strElements = strObj.getParametrizedList();
        // ...

        // With the hierarchy of interfaces
        StringInterface rightStrObj = new RightStringImplementation();

        List<String> rightStrElements = rightStrObj.getParametrizedList(); // This is right
        //List<Integer> wrongIntElements = rightStrObj.getParametrizedList(); // This does not compile because of type safety
    }
}
```

With your initial approach you may have problems with type casting if you are not careful. With a propper interface hierarchy you may get the benefits of type safety.

Also note that I changed your example variable name to iClass_Instance. Variable names in Java start with a lowercase character by convention.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. IClass_Instance was for "an instance of a variable of type IClass".

Comment: Now...sorry, re-reading you reply I got totally lost. What's the point in implementing an interface<T> if, when you declare it, you restrict the variable of being of a specific type? Doing what you suggest mean I have to declare a variable of IClass<String>, one IClass<Long>, and then fill the code with IF each time I need to call one of the Interface method to know which of the two objects I need to use...that is, it totally erase Interfaces usefulness of abstracting variables types but still being sure of them implementing specific methods. Am I wrong?

Comment: I edited the answer deleting incorrect information and adding a working code example.